# how to properly error handle XCUI element not found in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to write a do-try-catch in swift for my iOS UI test which uses XCUI testing. I am reading the error-handling section: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508
but am unsure of which error should be thrown when an element is not found.

```
func tapElement(string:String) throws {

    do{
        waitFor(app.staticTexts[string], 5)
        try app.staticTexts[string].tap()
    }
    catch {
        NSLog("Element was not found: \(string)")
        //how can i check specifically that the element was not found?
    }


}
```

....

```
func waitFor(element:XCUIElement, seconds waitSeconds:Double) {
    NSLog("Waiting for element: \(element)")
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
    expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(waitSeconds, handler: nil)
}
```

any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to try-catch finding elements in UI Testing. Ask the framework if the element `exists()` before trying to `tap()` it.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let element = app.staticTexts["item"]
if element.exists {
    element.tap()
} else {
    NSLog("Element does not exist")
}
```

Check out my [blog post on getting started with UI Testing](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/) for more specific examples, [like tapping an button](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-tap-a-button).

Comment: There are times that I would like to gracefully handle when elements are not found

Comment: I had already read through your blog, thanks it was a great source. but i am not looking for advice on tapping a button. any insight into using the try catch to gracefully handle errors would be greatly appreciated

Comment: *Why* are you trying to catch? See my edit to check if the element exists.

Comment: I thought it might be a better approach, but what you've put there is actually what i ended up doing. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `element.exists` AND `element.isHittable`

**element.exists** checks whether the element is an element of the UIApplication/ScrollView/..

**element.isHittable** determines if a hit point can be computed for the element.

If you don't check for both, than `element.tap()` throws the following error, for example, if the element is under the *keyboard*:

> Failed: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) TextField,...

Example code:

```
let textField = elementsQuery.textFields.allElementsBoundByIndex[i]

if textField.exists && textField.isHittable {
    textField.tap()
} else {
     // text field is not hittable or doesn't exist!
     XCTFail()
 }
```